# Summarising the key points of useful answers

Tags: discussion, answers

After a question I've asked has run its course and an answer has been accepted, is it worthwhile summarising the key points raised by the answers into a foot-note of the original question?

I realise that not all questions are suited for this, but on some of the more information-centric questions it would provide a useful, quick reference for future viewers.

*Edit*: An example.

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306250/c-equivalent-of-cs-funct-tresult) question I asked, all of the answers were excellent but none of them explicitly stated the solution I was looking for, so after I worked it out, I updated the answer to include the working solution.

Comment: If you provided some examples it may help your case, but I think your proposal isn't generally very necessary.

Comment: I disagree with the answers here and with @DanielDiPaolo's comment. I think it would very useful to be allowed to create a new post which gathers the answers given in different posts regarding a single topic. There is an example which I have just stumbled upon now regarding Scala's parameterless/empty-paren methods. There are various posts on this topic but NONE treat the matter fully. Rather the union of all the posts answers the question completely. But anyone searching this topic area has to trawl through all the posts. Surely it would be better to have all that info organised in one page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sure helps people looking for a quick solution.

But if you have the rights to edit and the answer is long, you can also provide a summary there.

Answer (score 4):

> is it worthwhile summarising the key points raised by the answers

What you've just described there is an answer. Rather than summarising in the *question*, add an answer yourself.